# SQL Query on finding the next number from the present number

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query on how to get the next element from the present element as a column. This is a sample of what I am trying to get

[Highlighted Column]

[image: 1]

The last element can be left blank, if nothing found after that. This has to be within a Group(GroupBy of a Group)

Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() in CTE (adjacent enumeration) then join by `t1.rn = t2.rn + 1`

Comment: Could you explain in a detailed way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function `lead`:

```
select * , LEAD(Date) over (partition by group order by date desc) NextNo.
from table
```

fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82vNwNt3G8HHpEFjUU3td8/0

Comment: Lead function doesnt seem to work properly when there is a case of repetitions of the values.

Comment: @akina that's not true , see the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/82vNwNt3G8HHpEFjUU3td8/0